# What's a "control block"

Tags: c++, boost

While reading the [boost::coroutine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/coroutine/intro.html) documentation, I came accross the term **control block** :

> The solution is that each coroutine has its own stack and **control-block**

While the notion of a **stack** is fairlly familiar, I've never encountered the term control block before. The following image may have provided some contextual (no pun intended) understanding of what a control block is

[image: source: boost documentation]

Since I can't google my way to a better explanation (the provided link to boost [context](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/context/doc/html/context/context.html) only made things more obscure), could anyone provide a solid definition and explain the workings of a control block?

thanks

Comment: It's called a control block because that's what the Boost folks decided to call it.  See http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/context/doc/html/context/context.html

Comment: It's the data used by the system to represent an execution context, ie. the state of the CPU registers, and some other system specific pieces of information (maybe signal mask and handlers on unix?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term dates back to the Process Control Block from IIRC CP/M, at least 4 decades. It's the block of data which describes a running context. Later on, threads got Thread Control Blocks Here the need for state meant a similar data structure, so the name Control Block makes sense. The only oddity is that usually these Control Blocks are OS structures, but boost coroutines aren't OS managed.